# linux command to find out if folder exists or not in a windows ftp server

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have connected a Windows server from a Linux machine via ftp. I want to find out if a particular folder exists or not in the Windows FTP server. How do i find out that using Linux shell scripting?

Comment: I believe this has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233277/bash-check-if-remote-directory-exists-using-ftp

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the standard ftp program, you can use the command `dir` to list all the files and folders on the server.

> **`dir`** - Lists files if connected.
>
> - dir -C = Will list the files in wide format.
> - dir -1 = Lists the files in bare format in alphabetic order
> - dir -r = Lists directory in reverse alphabetic order.
> - dir -R = Lists all files in current directory and sub directories.
> - dir -S = Lists files in bare format in alphabetic order.

Reference: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ftp.htm